# Is there an equivalent of PHP's hash_hmac in Python/Django?

Tags: php, python, django, sha256

I want to forward my visitors to a 3rd party paysite. This 3rd party will process their payment and POST to me a 64 character token generated from a unique order number and shared password using PHP's [hash_hmac](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash-hmac.php) using the sha256 algorithm, like so:

```
$token = hash_hmac("sha256", "12345", "sharedpassword");
```

Then I want to use the same algorithm on my end to generate the (hopefully) the same token to verify the user has paid. The problem is I cannot find an equivalent function or way to replicate the function in Python. The closest I've come is Python's [hashlib](http://docs.python.org/library/hashlib.html), but there doesn't appear to be a function that can take in 2 arguments - the data and the shared password. Does anyone know of an equivalent of hash_hmac that would be applicable in this case?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You want [`hmac`](http://docs.python.org/library/hmac.html).

```
hmac.new("sharedpassword", "12345", hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

or in python 3:

```
hmac.new(bytes("sharedpassword", 'UTF-8'), "12345".encode(), hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

Comment: Thank you! I guess my google-fu needs honing.

Comment: I get a TypeError for this code `raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__) TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'` on Python 3.8.5

Comment: @jeppoo1 This answer is 8+ years old and was written for Python 2; in Python 3 you'd pass a bytes object instead of a string.